# type() function SyntaxError in simple code

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm  trying to do a function that, given a number, tells you the numbers by which that number is divisible by.
Here's the code:

```
input_num=int(input("Introduce number: "))
divider=1
dividers=[]

while divider<=input_num:
    if type(input_num/divider)==int
    dividers.append(divider)
    divider=divider+1
print(dividers)
```

The error is in the type line, it says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Answer (score 0):

you missed the `:`
Also, in the same if statement, type is always float. Here is a working code:

```
input_num=int(input("Introduce number: "))
divider=1
dividers=[]

while divider<=input_num:
    if int(input_num/divider)==input_num/divider:
        dividers.append(divider)
    divider=divider+1
print(dividers)
```

Comment: Lol. I guess I didn't have to make a post about this...
Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem that I have now is that when I print(dividers), its blank.

Comment: The problem is, `type(input_num/divider)` is always a float. Replacing the if statement with `if int(input_num/divider)==input_num/divider:` solves the problem. The thing done here is we just compare the rounded integer with non-rounded float. I am editing the answer as well.

Comment: Also in your question, you only asked about the syntax error. That's why I only solved that problem

Comment: Yes, I just realized about that. Thank you anyways.